# How to fetch a single row from mysql workbench using code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to fetch a single row from my database but I can't seem to make it work. The problem is that the code is fetching the whole column instead. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Please help

```
<?php

defined ('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Agrivest_model extends CI_Model
```

{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->database();       
}
public function get_category_tb()
{

  $this->db->from('category_tb');
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query->result();

}
```

}

```
<?php foreach ($category_tb as $post){?>
<h4 class="category_name"><?php echo $post->category_name; ?> </h4>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public function __construct()
 {
   parent:: __construct();
   $this->load->database();       
 }
 public function get_category_tb()
 {

   $this->db->from('category_tb');
     $query=$this->db->get()->row();
    return $query->category_name;

  }
```